# Render the webpage in a specified version of IE dynamically

Tags: javascript

I have a webpage that is currently rendered to run in IE=7. Is there a way to change it dynamically? I am having issues with custom views being rendered in IE7 and I want to change it dynamically to IE8. This is what I have tried so far.

```
window.onload = function () {
    var metas = document.getElementsByTagName('meta');

    for (i = 0; i < metas.length; i++) {
        if (metas[i].getAttribute("content") == "IE=7") {
            metas[i].setAttribute("content", "IE=8");
        }
    } 
}
```

My webpage looks like this:

Somehow that meta content set to IE=7 is causing the problem with the alignments. If it could be changed to IE8 or removed altogether, that might just solve the problem.

But unfortunately nothing with code snippet above. Am I doing something wrong here? 
Guys any help on this would be much appreciated. Also can it be done only via JavaScript? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that even in IE's developer tools, switching the document mode requires a refresh of the page. So, the direct answer is "No, it cannot be done in JavaScript".

In my company's case, we use a serverside check to see what the user's user agent is, and sends a `<meta>` tag in the response based on what version of IE they're using. If you can change serverside code for this project, you would be better off changing that meta tag.

Comment: Katana314 thanks for the answer! My only other option would be to send it the dev guys to make it run in a different version.

Answer (score 0):

You could use conditionals to run code or use HTML depending on the IE version.

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
    <p>Welcome to Internet Explorer 8.</p>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: That can be done. But it would be a lot better if the clients dont have to change their browser versions every now and then. That might cause problems later. Its just a custom view page that needs to be rendered in a different version of IE. I appreciate the answer though!!